# Use data from .txt and then applicate calculation with a function, and then plotting the results

Tags: python

I am trying to extract data from a .txt file (Aperture, ShutterSpeed) and then apply some calculations with a function I already created, and have the results plotted in a certain way.

What is the best way to do it in Python?

I have already read the data:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import math

filename='/home/stagiaire/Bureau/derr.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')
Fnumber = [row.split(' ')[0] for row in data]
ShutterSpeed = [row.split(' ')[1] for row in data]
```

But it is not accepted in my function that calculates the Lux value,

```
def Calcul_Lux(Fnumber,ShutterSpeed):
    x=math.pow(Fnumber,2)/(ShutterSpeed)
    IL=math.log(x,2)
    lux = math.pow(2,IL) * 2.5
    return lux
```

The idea is to have my data as a list I guess (two columns Fnumber and ShutterSpeed), but I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Please show your call to `Calcul_Lux`

Comment: so you have pairs of numbers in a file and you want to end up with a list of numbers from running those pairs through your function?

Comment: here is the call 

Calcul_Lux(Fnumber,ShutterSpeed)

TypeError: a float is required

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I have a txt file that contains 2 rows 30 float numbers, I need to do a calculation (Calulate the Lux) with each row. And when I finish plot the results I get to compare with other results.

Comment: It sounds like your data is stored as strings in the lists. You need to convert them to floats before the call.

Comment: @quamrana and how to ? Excuse me but I am new to Python. 
For example I tried e=float(x) but doesn't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Input from string to float

When reading the data, it will be read as a string, this means that the values you obtain in Fnumber and ShutterSpeed are also of type string. As the Calcul_Lux function expects numbers, you need to typecast the string values as numbers.

To typecast a string into a floating point number you can use `float(<object>)`, if you prefer to have an integer you can use `int(<object>)`

To solve your problem you can change the assignment of `Fnumber` and `ShutterSpeed` like this:

```
Fnumber      = [float(row.split(' ')[0]) for row in data]
ShutterSpeed = [float(row.split(' ')[1]) for row in data]
```

#### Call function in one go

To call the function for each value and return it as a list, we first need to pack the Fnumber and ShutterSpeed into a single list of tuples. We can do this using the `zip()` function:

```
tuples = zip(Fnumber, ShutterSpeed)
```

Next we can call the function `Calcul_Lux` for each item in the list using the `map()` function, which basically executes the given lambda function on each item in the list:

```
output = map(lambda tup: Calcul_Lux(tup[0], tup[1]), tuples)
```

This will return all you values as a list.

#### Plotting values

To plot the output and compare them with a constant line we can use the `matplotlib` library. We can use its `plot()` function to plot our output as points and we can draw a comparison line using the `axhline()` function. In the end the code to plot would look something like this.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt # To import the matplotlib library

plt.plot(range(len(output)), output, 'ro')          # To draw the points from the output
plt.axhline(y=48000)            # To draw the 48.000 comparison line
plt.show()                      # To show the plot
```

The `ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1` is caused because we only provided the y values, without any x values. To plot the output according to index we can change the `plt.plot(output, 'ro')` to include an x value like this:

```
plt.plot(range(len(output)), output, 'ro')
```

Comment: Thank you. I just tried it and the problem with floats is solved I think, the only thing now is that my function is giving me only one result, I nead to have all the 30 results in a list or somethins, to use the data and plot it after.

Comment: I added an explanation to calling the function for each value in one go.

Comment: thank you very much that worked perfectly ! Now I just have to plot all the results in a way to compare them with a value like 48.000 (the valuer 48000 will be a line and all my 30 results will be points arround). Do you have an idea ???

Comment: You're welcome, I also added plotting the values to my explanation.

Comment: it gives this message Error 

ValueError: ordinal must be >= 1

in the line 

plt.plot(output, 'ro')

Comment: To precise, I want to do a scatter plot

Comment: I added a solution to the ValueError problem

Comment: Thank you. Just took it as an a solution this question

Answer (score 1):

```
with open(filename) as f:
    pairs = ((float(x) for x in line.split()) for line in f)
    luxes = [Calcul_Lux(fnum, speed) for fnum, speed in pairs]
```

Here's how I would do it.  `pairs` is a generator that yields a generator of floats for each line.  The list comprehension accepts that generator, pulls out the two values and passes them to `Calcul_Lux`

Comment: Thank you very much sir.

Answer (score 0):

Your Calcul_Lux funtion is expecting to be passed two values (f-number and shutterspeed), but you have your values in two lists. You can zip the lists together, which looks like this:

```
>>> one = [1,2,3]
>>> two = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> zip(one, two)
[(1, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

And then pass the values one at a time to your function, so:

```
for fn, ss in zip(Fnumber, ShutterSpeed):
    Calcul_Lux(fn,ss)
```

Comment: i just did it and the error is TypeError: a float is required  (in the line of x if my calcul_lux funciton)

Comment: Yes, I missed the point that the other answerer picked up - you will need to convert your strings into floats. You will need to make their change as well.

Answer (score 0):

You may be better off extracting the data like this:

```
import math

def Calcul_Lux(Fnumber,ShutterSpeed):
    x=math.pow(Fnumber,2)/(ShutterSpeed)
    IL=math.log(x,2)
    lux = math.pow(2,IL) * 2.5
    return lux


filename='/home/stagiaire/Bureau/derr.txt'
with open(filename) as f:
    data = f.read()
data = data.split('\n')
cameraData = [(float(row.split(' ')[0]),float(row.split(' ')[1])) for row in data]

luxes=[Calcul_Lux(Fnumber,ShutterSpeed) for Fnumber,ShutterSpeed in cameraData]
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, it gvies me a message error

[0]),float(row.split(' ')[1]) for row in data]
                                                                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax